# What config needed for 75fps in WebGL application?

Tags: three.js, webgl, oculus, virtual-reality, webvr

I want to make webgl application (using ThreeJS) for Oculus Rift DK2. DK2 need to get 75fps rendering output for the best view. But I have problem with it: one PC output 75fps, another - 60fps only.

My PC configs:

1. PC1 (outputs 75fps)

   - Intel Core i5
   - 10Gb DDR3
   - GeForce GTX 650
   - Windows 10
   - Firefox Nighty with WebVR addon
2. PC2 (outputs 60fps)

   - Intel Core i7
   - 16Gb DDR3
   - GeForce GTX 650
   - Windows 7
   - Firefox Nighty with WebVR addon

What affects to config PC2 that doesn't output 75fps?

Comment: And your screen refresh rate is... ?

Comment: 75hz in both. May be browser not use hardware acceleration in Pc2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

- Oculus runtime 0.8 (direct mode only)
- Geforce drivers v.358.70-beta (as per the 0.8 runtime instructions)
- Firefox Nightly w/ following flags (set via about:config)

  - dom.vr.enabled: true
  - gfx.vr.mirror-texture: true
  - layout.frame_rate: 75 (to match DK2 refresh)

https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/web-vr-discuss/2015-November/000929.html